# Issue while applying fade in/fade out animation

Tags: css, typescript, animation

I have a page with several buttons; clicking action on them triggers the fade-in/fade-out animation. During that animation, some contents of the div get changed.

Everything works fine, however, before fading animation starts, div disappears for some half of a second (and it doesn't look good). How can I prevent disappearing it, just get invisible and then visible again (without any changes to height)? Setting height to 100% didn't help.

CSS

```
.afterClick {
  -webkit-animation: fadeinout 0.6s linear forwards !important;
  animation: fadeinout 0.6s linear forwards !important;
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="some-class" (click)="setAnimation()">

<div class="afterClick" *ngIf="checkVisiblity == 'Y'">
some contents
</div>
```

TS

```
public checkVisiblity = 'Y';

setAnimation() {
  let context = this;
  context.checkVisiblity = 'N';
  setTimeout(function() {
    context.checkVisiblity = 'Y';
  }, 50);
}
```

Comment: Can we have a working example of your code in stack-blitz please

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Actually, I have resolved the issues above. The reason was in another div, which was wrapping the page and had grid settings inside. Looks like there was some conflict with those settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) to the .afterClick class

```
.afterClick {
  -webkit-animation: fadeinout 0.6s linear forwards !important;
  animation: fadeinout 0.6s linear forwards !important;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;}
```

Comment: Thanks, have tried it - but unfortunately, there was no effect...